# Delaying Intercept responses in Cypress

Tags: reactjs, cypress

I am writing cypress tests, and I want to test a feature of our program which will display data as it begins to appear. This could be a list with several hundred elements, and in order to speed it up, we break the request up into multiple requests.

The first request will fetch the first 50 items, the second request the next 100, etc.

I want to ensure that after the first request returns, the list contains 50 items, and that after the second request returns, the list contains 150 items.

What I don't know how to do, is reliably delay the intercept responses so that I can return the first 50, check the list length, then allow more data to come in.

This is what I have so far:

```
const baseUrl = 'https://example.io/listData*'
const document = 'public_document_10101'

cy.intercept(
  {
    url: baseUrl,
    query: {
      limit: '50',
      'document': document
    },
  },
  { fixture: 'first-response.js' }
).as('firstResponse')

cy.intercept(
  {
    url: baseUrl,
    query: {
      limit: '100',
      skip: '50',
      'document': document
    },
  },
  { fixture: 'second-response.js' }
).as('secondResponse')
```

I don't believe that something like `cy.wait('@firstResponse')` will do what I want, as this doesn't prevent the second one from return at all. I'm open to using a delay of some kind, however it would be really nice if there was a wait to completely block it until I say so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like the functionality you want [Throttle or delay response all incoming responses](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#Throttle-or-delay-response-all-incoming-responses)

```
// Code from Real World App (RWA)
// cypress/support/index.ts
import { isMobile } from './utils'
import './commands'
// Throttle API responses for mobile testing to simulate real world conditions
if (isMobile()) {
  cy.intercept({ url: 'http://localhost:3001/**', middleware: true }, (req) => {
    req.on('response', (res) => {
      // Throttle the response to 1 Mbps to simulate a mobile 3G connection
      res.setThrottle(1000)
    })
  })
}
```

Or maybe [Static Response object](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#StaticResponse-objects) with fixture property and delay property

```
{
  /**
   * Serve a fixture as the response body.
   */
  fixture?: string
  /**
   * Serve a static string/JSON object as the response body.
   */
  body?: string | object | object[]
  /**
   * HTTP headers to accompany the response.
   * @default {}
   */
  headers?: { [key: string]: string }
  /**
   * The HTTP status code to send.
   * @default 200
   */
  statusCode?: number
  /**
   * If 'forceNetworkError' is truthy, Cypress will destroy the browser connection
   * and send no response. Useful for simulating a server that is not reachable.
   * Must not be set in combination with other options.
   */
  forceNetworkError?: boolean
  /**
   * Milliseconds to delay before the response is sent.
   */
  delay?: number
  /**
   * Kilobits per second to send 'body'.
   */
  throttleKbps?: number
}
```

Comment: hmm, yea the delay property is working. That's not a bad solution. Would be cool if I could actually programmatically control when it gets returned, but this will work.

Comment: You mean trigger the 2nd request from within the test, after first response is validated? There is probably a way using a function on the routeHandler part of intercept. Would have to be recursive. Not sure it's worth the extra code and potential for bugs. A fixed delay of 100ms should work and would not be noticeable in the test run.

Comment: Yea, that is what I was hoping to achieve, however if the results are stubbed and I can add a delay, then I'm confident that will work as well. At this point in time I'm not going to go through the trouble of trying to hack together a solution, as the extra delay in the code is really no big deal.

Answer (score 8):

You can also use setDelay. [Cypress Docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#Ending-the-response-with-res-send)

```
cy.intercept({ url: 'http://localhost:3001/**', middleware: true }, (req) => {
  req.on('response', (res) => {
    // Wait for delay in milliseconds before sending the response to the client.
    res.setDelay(1000)
  })
})
```